# Bitwise operations, comparing a u32 with a byte array

Tags: rust, comparison, bit-manipulation, byte, bitwise-operators

Lets say I have the value 1025 as a byte array and the value 1030 as usize. How would I go about comparing if the byte array is bigger, lesser or equal without deserializing it?

I'm completely stuck, I assume the easisest way is to get the biggest bytes of the byte array, its position, then bitshift the u32 and see if any bits in the byte is set, if not the byte array is bigger.

In short I want to write some functions to be able to decide if a > b, a < b and a == b.

To use a code example

```
fn is_greater(a: &[u8], b: usize) -> bool {
    // a is LE, so reverse and get the largest bytes
    let c = a.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .rev()
        .filter_map(|(i, b)| ( if *b != 0 { return Some((i, *b)); } else { None }))
        .collect::<Vec<(usize, u8)>>();

    for (i, be) in c {
        let k = (b >> (i * 8)) & 255;
        println!("{}, {}", be, k);

        return be as usize > k
    }

    false
}
```

EDIT: Should have clarified, the byte array can be any integer, unsigned integer or float. Simply any integer bincode::serialize can serialize.

I also had in mind to avoid converting the byte array, comparison is supposed to be used on 100000 of byte arrays, so I assume bit operations is the preferred way.

Comment: This looks like a case of premature optimization to me. I doubt that anything you can do will be faster than simply deserializing the bincode and comparing the deserialized integer.

Comment: Properly-written deserialization is extremely fast.

Answer (score 2):

No need for all those extra steps. The basic problem is to know if the integer encoded in the byte-array is `little endian`, `big endian` or `native endian`. Knowing that, you can use [`usize::from_??_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.usize.html#method.from_le_bytes) to convert a fixed-size array to an integer; use the [`TryFrom`-trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) to get the fixed-size array from the slice.

```
fn is_greater(b: &[u8], v: usize) -> Result<bool, std::array::TryFromSliceError> {
    use std::convert::TryFrom;
    Ok(usize::from_le_bytes(<[u8; 8]>::try_from(b)?) > v)
}
```

This function will return an error if the byte-slice is smaller than 8 bytes, in which case there is no way to construct a `usize`; you can also convert to `u32` or even `u16`, upcast that to `usize` and then do the comparison. Also notice that this example uses `from_le_bytes`, assuming the bytes-slice contains an integer encoded as `little endian`.

Comment: Which, by the way, is exactly what bincode does when deserializing the value, so you might as well call `bincode::deserialize`.